# VS.NET Local Report grouping

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reportviewer, localreport

I'm trying to create a report in VS.NET 2022 Local Report that groups rows by certain attributes.
For example, my dataset returns this information

[image]

What I need is report that displays the information this way:
[image]

In other words: a top section for each group and and list of records for each group.

All examples I've seen so far only allow me to have the group section as the first column on the left.

Is that possible to do? any examples I can check?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also what is "VS.Net"? With the tags I thought the VS might mean "Visual Studio" but there's no such thing as "Visual Studio .Net"; Visual Studio can be used to develop many in languages (and GUIs), not just .Net languages. Do you mean VB.Net?